# submit button is not binded when bootstrap modal open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a weird problem.
 I have one bootstrap modal.
 I am loading data by calling ajax on that modal. 
I want to submit the form using jQuery ajax, so I have used event.preventDefault() on submitting the form.

```
// add_product_form is ID of my form
$('#add_product_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var myform = document.getElementById("add_product_form");
  var fd = new FormData(myform );
  var url = $(this).attr('action');
  var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
  var _this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    data:fd,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    method:'POST',
    success:function(result){

    }
  });
});
});
```

What should happen is it should submit the data using ajax.
 but it is redirecting to action URL not calling the action URL by ajax. 
When I select product category and products name in dropdown, it works fine.
 I don't understand why.

From my view click event is binded to submit button when I select the product. 
Please let me know any other suggestion.
 How can i solve this?

My modal code which is loaded by ajax

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Add Product</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="group-form">
      {!! Form::model($quote_details,['id'=>'add_product_form','url'=>action('AjaxController@CheckProductExist')]) !!}
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          {!! Form::label('fk_product_class_id','Category') !!}
          {!! Form::select('fk_product_class_id', $quote_details->getCategoryInDropdown(), Input::old('fk_product_class_id'), ['data-save'=>'false','placeholder' => 'Select Category...','class'=>'form-control category_select']) !!}
          {{ csrf_field() }}
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div><br>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label>Product</label>
          <select name="product_id" class="form-control product_name_dd_modal">
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div><br>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          {!! Form::text('qty',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Quantity']) !!}
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <input type="hidden" name="quoteid" value="{{$_GET['id'] or ''}}">
        <button type="submit" id="product-submit" class="save_btn"><img src="{{ url('/img/save_img.png')}}" class="cursor" ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      {!! Form::close() !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if your submit button name or id is submit then it will not work, change those .

Comment: try and post most of the thing including the modal.

Comment: I have added modal code

Comment: What about post form data on button click, something like `$('#add_product_form_submit_button').on('click', function (e){ //ajax post});

Comment: @NikhilChaudhary id is product-submit . that is not affecting anything if i remove it or include it

Comment: @demo why this code is not working on some cases and working on some cases ? I am trying to find reason for that here

Comment: @Sudhanshusharma can you tell, is your jquery code calling or not calling at all ?

Comment: yes. it calls when i select product name in drop down, otherwise it won't call. please read the lines which i wrote in ques.